# SCNAction block preventing memory deallocation

Tags: ios, swift

I've got this code that makes a reference to self in a SCNAction block in the following way:

```
spawnAction = SCNAction.runBlock({ node in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
         [weak self] in
         if let actualSelf = self {
             actualSelf.spawnDelegate?.spawnRiverCrosser(node.position)
          }
      })
  })
```

When I set this class to nil, my deinit method is not called. It is called through if I comment out the line

```
actualSelf.spawnDelegate?.spawnRiverCrosser(node.position)
```

I read about the retain cycle and I do understand that the method won't be called if I have any strong reference hanging around, but as many StackOverflow answers suggest, by using the closure [weak self] the problem should be solved. I don't get why it is not working.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the root cause here, but it probably has something to do with your closure within a closure. You shouldn't need to dispatch to the main queue here anyway, as SCNAction.runBlock should call its block on the main queue.

Comment: By the way, if you're only making one call on your weak self, optional chaining is equivalent and a lot shorter: `[weak self] in self?.spawnDelegate?.spawnWhatever...`